# Gradle dependencies for Android app which uses google cloud endpoint client libs

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

While following along with the demo in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Sp4Lr3Qmcw

I noticed that at 16:56 in the video :

http://youtu.be/7Sp4Lr3Qmcw?t=16m56s

the presenter pastes the following snippet into build.gradle of the android app :

```
compile('com.google.todotxt.backend:taskApi:v1-1.17.0-rc-SNAPSHOT') {
  exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
}

compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
 exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
 exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
}
```

but does not explain how he got those lines.

The previous step of :

```
==> ./gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs
```

also does not show what artifacts were created and what the names of the artifacts were.

So, it is not clear how the presenter obtained the names of the artifacts from the previous step.

Does anyone know how the presenter was able to figure out what the names are, of the artifacts generated from the the install-client-libraries-step are.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That video is from an older version of Android Studio.  Updated instructions for integrating an appengine backend with your android application are available at : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates

Basically there is some cross module dependency configuration that tells your android module to pull the endpoints artifact from the appengine module.  The new flow doesn't use a Maven repository anymore.

However if you still want to find out how the names are discovered.  You have to go into the build directory of your appengine project, into the client libraries folder, unzip those zips and looks in the build.gradle file for the client library to see the artifact output name.